# EF 5.0 set column equal to the default (computed) value of another column in one transaction

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table that has an Identity column and another column needs to have its value based on the computed identity column.

My EF code looks like this:

```
var context = new DBEntities();
var newTableRow = new TableRow();
newTableRow.Column1 = newTableRow.ComputedColumn;
context.TableRows.Add(newTableRow);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If ComputedColumn is an IDENTITY and Column1 is a nullable varchar(50) I would expect the value of Column1 to be the same as the ComputedColumn but it is null.
I have even tried this:

```
var context = new DBEntities();
var newTableRow = new TableRow();
context.TableRows.Add(newTableRow);
context.SaveChanges();
newTableRow.Column1 = newTableRow.ComputedColumn;
context.SaveChanges();
```

AND

```
var context = new DBEntities();
var newTableRow = new TableRow();
context.TableRows.Add(newTableRow);
context.SaveChanges();
var getTableRow = context.TableRows.Single(r => r.ComputedColumn == newTableRow.ComputedColumn);
getTableRow.Column1 = newTableRow.ComputedColumn.ToString();
context.SaveChanges();
```

Keep in mind that this is part of a larger transaction.  What I don't want to do is complete the transaction then in a separate transaction do another update.  I would like to keep everything in one transaction.  This had been working in an insert proc before.

Thanks,

Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second an third example should work if `ComputedColumn` has `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. But they have separate transactions, which you don't want.

Your first example can't work. When a column has `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, EF reads the identity value back when executing `SaveChanges`. It is not aware of any special instruction you might have tried to convey with

```
newTableRow.Column1 = newTableRow.ComputedColumn;
```

As for EF, it's just an assignment with an empty value.

Maybe the best alternative is to add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to your database table. You will kill two birds with one stone:

- It is transactional, because the computed column just re-displays the  identity column
- You prevent redundancy and possible value conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about just adding a UDF to do this and set the default value equal to the UDF (since you can't set a default value equal to another column).  The strange thing is I know I have a value after the first SaveChanges because that is being used to save the child records in the same transaction.  There might be something else going on with the EDMX.  I'll keep digging.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need an UDF. A computed column is not the same as a column with a default value! It is a read-only column with an expression. Good luck digging, sounds a bit weird indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I just reviewed the model and you're right there was a change I didn't notice. Column1 had been set as a computed value.  Removing that value should fix the problem.